# Local version of Achecker tool different than the online version

Tags: web, accessibility

I installed the Achecker from http://www.atutor.ca/achecker/ 
and ran the guidelines to get a report. 
Earlier we were doing the same with http://Achecker.ca 
There are few guidelines are missing in the local version. They are not similar. Is there any difference and if yes is there a way to upgrade the techniques to latest on the local version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version from the Web site is the Achecker version 1.3 (25/11/2011).
See sourceforge history here:http://sourceforge.net/projects/achecker/files/achecker/

You can find on GitHub, a version of June 2014:
https://github.com/inclusive-design/AChecker

Comment: Thanks Adam, I just installed the version in the Github, It is giving following error:
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\dev\xampp\xampp\htdocs\anew\checker\index.php on line 165

I am trying to find out if there are compatiblitiy issue with my current version of php. Any new versions required?

Comment: Hi Adam, Found the reason. The checker/index.php is using  $allowed_file_extensions = ["html", "htm"];
which is a array from Php5.4 onwards.